# Pig - Multiple join conditions

Tags: apache-pig

I have to use 4 join conditions on 5 tables, with a filter condition on one of the tables.

```
TableB.ColumnX = 'A' and TableB.ColumnY = 'B'

TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA and
TableB.ColumnB (left outer) = TableC.ColumnB and
TableB.ColumnB  = TableD.ColumnB and
TableD.ColumnB = TableE.ColumnB
```

These attempts were successful:

(i)  filter as a single statement
(ii) one join condition each as single statement (meaning 4 independent join statements)

But I want all the joins combined/consolidated.

Please help with some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Is the schema of the tables differs? What type of joins do you  want?  (Inner/outer/full?) If you can explain more the data and the final goal that would be easier to help.

Comment: @kecso : Yes, the schema of these tables differ but their join column data types are compatible/identical. One of the joins is a left outer ( the 2nd one, as mentioned in the question ). Hope this info helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to join on 2 different columns of B when joining with 2 different tables (column A when joining with TableA and column B when joining with TableC), and since it also involves OUTER join, you can not achieve this in SINGLE JOIN statement.

The best way to achieve this in minimum statements is like below:

```
TableB = FILTER TableB BY ColumnX = 'A' AND ColumnY = 'B';
JoinAB = JOIN TableA BY ColumnA, TableB BY ColumnB;
JoinBDE = JOIN TableB BY ColumnB, TableD BY ColumnB, TableE BY ColumnB
JoinABDE = JOIN JoinAB BY TableB::ColumnB, JoinBDE BY TableB::ColumnB;
JoinABCDE = JOIN JoinABDE BY TableB::ColumnB LEFT OUTER, TableC
```

Fyi, from http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28outer%29:
"Outer joins will only work for two-way joins; to perform a multi-way outer join, you will need to perform multiple two-way outer join statements"

Comment: Gaurav:This info really helped. Your input saved my day. Waiting for more inputs/views from the community. I will be tracking this query for one more week, before I accept the answer. Many thanks for your time!!

Comment: You're welcome @Marco99. I'd be glad if someone comes up less number of queries. 
As a general advice, I would not recommend reducing the number of statements in your PIG script, as pig scripts are usually optimized before running. I would give more preference to optimizing/reducing the actual operations (mapper/reducer) that runs during runtime.